# Play! Eclipse Not a valid argument

Tags: eclipse, playframework, playframework-2.0

Using play framework 2.4.6. I created a new app using activator. I did nothing else but these instructions here to "Eclipsify" the project  https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/IDE

This is the error I get

```
 [myapp] $ eclipse
[error] Not a valid command: eclipse (similar: help, alias)
[error] Not a valid project ID: eclipse
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Not a valid key: eclipse (similar: deliver, licenses, clean)
[error] eclipse
```

I tried clean, compile I added this line `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "4.0.0")` to my project `plugins.sbt` file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command is `eclipse` if you are in the play console and `activator eclipse` if you are not in the play console.

Make sure your project has been compile before running the eclipse command, as the play docs indicate: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/IDE#Setup-sbteclipse

Answer (score 1):

The command is

> activator eclipse

not

> eclipse